# Bundle error after upgrading Expo to SDK 42

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I upgraded expo from sdk 39 to sdk 42 and I've got bundle error

```
Unable to resolve module ./TransitionProgressContext from E:\reactNative\BooKing\node_modules\react-native-screens\src\index.native.tsx:
```

it shows error with react-native-screens. I have it in version 3.4.0

**Package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.3.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.5",
    "expo": "^42.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.1.2",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "^10.2.2",
    "expo-camera": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-permissions": "^12.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.4",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "~2.6.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.43.0",
    "react-native-gl-model-view": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-safe-module": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7",
    "react-router-native": "^5.2.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20",
    "unimodules-permissions-interface": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

How to fix this problem? I don't know why it's appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I needed just to clear cache with command `expo r -c`